# Linking 3 tables together in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to link 3 database table together through one MySQL request.

**Database structure :**

Table1 :

- table1_id (exemple: 1)
- table1_name (exemple: hello world)

Table2 :

- table2_id (exemple: empty)
- table2_name (exemple: empty)

Table3 :

- table3_id (exemple: 1)
- table3_name (exemple: random_name

**MySQL Request**

```
SELECT * FROM table1 AS a, table2 AS b, table3 AS c 
WHERE a.table1_id = b.table2_id 
 AND a.table1_id = c.table3_id AND table3_name = "random-name"
```

**Problem**

The previous request won't display any result because `table2` is empty. Do you have an idea how I could get the data coming from table 1 & 2, letting `table3`'s fields empty without using two requests ?

Answer (score 2):

You should change your request to use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`:

```
select *
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2
  on t1.table1_id = t2.table2_id
left join table3 t3
  on t1.table1_id = t3.table2_id
  and t3.table3_name = 'random-name'
```

The `INNER JOIN` produces a set of data if the id exists in all tables. The `LEFT JOIN` will return records from `table1` even if there are no records in `table2` or `table3`.

If you need help learning about join syntax, here is a great [visual explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Working perfectly! Thank you so much!!

Comment: @JeremyWagemans Happy to help, if this answer or any answer is helpful to you then be sure to accept it via the checkmark to the left of it. It will help future visitors and you will get site reputation for it.

Answer (score 0):

Couple thoughts:

- Don't use `SELECT *`, name the columns explicitly
- Don't use implicit join syntax; use `ON` clauses
- To preserve rows that do not "match" on a join condition, use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

Therefore, try this:

```
SELECT  a.table1_id, a.table1_name
      , b.table2_id, b.table2_name
      , c.table3_id, c.table3_name 
FROM   table1 AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 AS b
ON     b.table2_id = a.table1_id
JOIN table3 AS c
ON     c.table3_id = a.table1_id 
WHERE  c.table3_name = "random-name"
```